# Как сделать остановку при столкновение с твердым объектом в java?

Tags: java

Написал код чтобы узнать столкнулся танк или нет:

```
Update(){
for(Point p : brickCoords) {//в brickCoords координаты x и y
   if((Math.abs(p.x - Player.newX) <= (SCALE + Player.SPRITE_SCALE * Player.scalee) - 10) && (Math.abs(p.y - Player.newY) <= (SCALE + Player.SPRITE_SCALE * Player.scalee) - 10)) { //newX & newY координаты танка

        }
      }
```

но как сделать чтобы когда игрок сталкивался с объектом, танк останавливался, я смог только родить идею сделать переменную скорости 0(но это не то), вот код класса игрока:

```
public class Player extends Entity{

public static final int SPRITE_SCALE = 16;
public static final int SPRITE_ROTATE = 1;

private static float scale;
public static float speedPlayer = 1.90f;
public static float newX;
public static float newY;
public static float scalee;


public enum Rotate{

    NORTH(0 * SPRITE_SCALE,  0 * SPRITE_SCALE, 1 * SPRITE_SCALE, 1 * SPRITE_SCALE),
    EAST(6 * SPRITE_SCALE, 0 * SPRITE_SCALE, 1 * SPRITE_SCALE, 1 * SPRITE_SCALE),
    SOUTH(4 * SPRITE_SCALE, 0 * SPRITE_SCALE, 1 * SPRITE_SCALE, 1 * SPRITE_SCALE),
    WEST(2 * SPRITE_SCALE, 0 * SPRITE_SCALE, 1 * SPRITE_SCALE, 1 * SPRITE_SCALE);

    private int x, y, w, h;

    Rotate(int x, int y, int w, int h){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;

    }
    protected BufferedImage texture(TextureAtlas atlas) {
        return atlas.cut(x, y, w, h);
    }
}

private Rotate rotate;
private Map<Rotate, Sprite> spriteMap;
private float speed;

public Player(float x, float y, float scale, float speed, TextureAtlas atlas){
    super(EntityType.Player, x, y);

    rotate = rotate.NORTH;
    spriteMap = new HashMap<Rotate, Sprite>();
    this.scale = scale;
    this.speed = speed;

    for(Rotate r : Rotate.values()) {
        SpritePice pice = new SpritePice(r.texture(atlas), SPRITE_ROTATE, SPRITE_SCALE);
        Sprite sprite = new Sprite(pice, scale);
        spriteMap.put(r, sprite);
    }
}

@Override
public void Update(Input input){
    scalee = scale;
        newX = x;
        newY = y;

    if(input.getKey(KeyEvent.VK_W)) {
         rotate = rotate.NORTH;
         newY -= speed;

    }else if(input.getKey(KeyEvent.VK_S)) {
         rotate = rotate.SOUTH;
         newY += speed;

    }else if(input.getKey(KeyEvent.VK_A)) {
         rotate = rotate.WEST;
         newX -= speed;   
        }else if(input.getKey(KeyEvent.VK_D)) {
                 rotate = rotate.EAST;
                 newX += speed;    
    }     

    if(newX < 0) {

          newX = 0;

    }else if(newX >= game.WIDTH - SPRITE_SCALE * scale){        

        newX = game.WIDTH - SPRITE_SCALE * scale;
    }

    if(newY < 0) {

       newY = 0;

    }else if(newY >= game.HEIGHT - SPRITE_SCALE * scale){       

       newY = game.HEIGHT - SPRITE_SCALE * scale;
        }   
        x = newX;
        y = newY;
                newX = x;
        newY = y;
            speed = speedPlayer;

}

@Override
public void render(Graphics2D g){
    spriteMap.get(rotate).render(g, x, y);
 }
    }
```

если я не скинул какой-то важной инфы напишите, я отредачу

Comment: когда я прочитал "твердый объект", то я подумал что это новой вид абстракции

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы узнать касаются разные объекты или нет, можно воспользоваться готовым классом `Rectangle`.

```
if(new Rectangle(player.x,player.y,player.width,player.height)).intersects(new Rectangle(object.x,object.y,object.width,object.height))) {
    // касаются
}
```

Или взглянуть на метод изнутри и сделать на его основе:

```
public boolean intersects(ReadableRectangle r) {
    int tw = this.width;
    int th = this.height;
    int rw = r.getWidth();
    int rh = r.getHeight();
    if (rw <= 0 || rh <= 0 || tw <= 0 || th <= 0) {
        return false;
    }
    int tx = this.x;
    int ty = this.y;
    int rx = r.getX();
    int ry = r.getY();
    rw += rx;
    rh += ry;
    tw += tx;
    th += ty;
    //      overflow || intersect
    return ((rw < rx || rw > tx) && (rh < ry || rh > ty) && (tw < tx || tw > rx) && (th < ty || th > ry));
}
```